# Python / Spark cast multiple variables - columns as double type

Tags: python, variables, apache-spark, pyspark

I am translating Scala / Spark deep learning model into Python / PySpark. After reading the df all variables are interpreted as strings type. I need to cast them as float. 
Doing this one by one is easy, I think it would be like this:

```
format_number(result['V1'].cast('float'),2).alias('V1')
```

, but there is 31 columns 
How to do it all at once.
The columns are "V1" to "V28" and "Time", "Amount", "Class"

Scala solution to it is this:

```
// cast all the column to Double type.
val df = raw.select(((1 to 28).map(i => "V" + i) ++ Array("Time", "Amount", "Class")).map(s => col(s).cast("Double")): _*)
```

https://github.com/intel-analytics/analytics-zoo/blob/master/apps/fraudDetection/Fraud%20Detction.ipynb

How to do the same in PySpark?

Answer (score 3):

Use comprehensions:

```
result.select([
    format_number(result[c].cast('float'),2).alias(c) for c in result.columns
])
```